# Django "NameError: name 'Database is not defined' while running on virtualenv

Tags: python, django, database, pip

I'm running python 3.4 and Django 1.6.5 , as soon as I run my app I get this error

```
  File "/home/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 42, in <module>
      DatabaseError = Database.DatabaseError
  NameError: name 'Database' is not defined
```

Any idea why this is happening ?
I already tried removing and reinstalling django through PIP but It didnt work

Comment: What is your database settings ? Though chem1st is right, My guess is, you will face this issue even if you upgrade to a later version of django because your settings is incorrect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.4 is not supported by Django 1.6 version. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.6/#python-compatibility)